# Tesseract couldn't load any languages

Tags: ios, objective-c

The `TESSDATA_PREFIX` environment variable is set to the parent directory of your `"tessdata"` directory.
Failed loading language 'eng'
Tesseract couldn't load any languages!

I can't open below path to set `TESSDATA_PREFIX` environment variable is set to parent directory of `"tessdata"` directory.

```
/Users/syzygy01/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/3C2CC079-D784-432D-A79A-C5336017E69C/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/61ADADE0-8CFD-4815-8F33-19B0DA676619/TesstractTest.app/tessdata/eng.traineddata
```

Answer (score 1):

Please keep you traning data file inside tessdata folder and follow this code :

```
import net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract;
import net.sourceforge.tess4j.TesseractException;

 public class OCR_POC {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws TesseractException {

String inputFilePath ="F:/my_documents/issues.pdf";
Tesseract   tesseract = new Tesseract();
tesseract.setDatapath("F:/Tesseract/tessdata/");
//tesseract.setLanguage("chi_sim");
//tesseract.setLanguage("eng");// english is default langauge
String  fullText= tesseract.doOCR(new File (inputFilePath));
System.out.println("Full text : "+fullText);

 }
}
```

Maven repository for pom.xml :

```
<dependency>
<groupId>net.sourceforge.tess4j</groupId>
 <artifactId>tess4j</artifactId>
<version>${tess4j}</version>
</dependency>
```